# mysql fastest 2 table query

Tags: php, mysql

**Situation:** 2 tables, the first (Persons) storing person names and some other data, and the second (Phones) storing their phone numbers. There can be multiple phone numbers per person (thats why I am using separate tables in the first place).

**Goal:** Select everything so that in the end I'd have a php array like this:

```
array
(
'0' => array
       (
        'name' => 'John Smith'
        // other values from table Persons...
        'Phones' => array('0' => '12345', '1' => '324343') // from Phones table

        ),
'1' => array
       (
        'name' => 'Adam Smith'
        // other values from table Persons...
        'Phones' => array('0' => '645646', '1' => '304957389', '2' => '9435798') // from Phones table

        )
);
```

ETC.

Phones.person_id = Persons.id

What would be the fastest way to do this? Fastest in a sense of program execution time, not the coding time. I could do simple JOIN but in this case I'd get many duplicate rows, i.e. for each phone I get all the data of the same person again and again in each row if you see what I mean. So I need to work on the array in PHP side. Maybe there's a better way?

Answer (score 1):

One query. Check for typos:

```
$return = array();
$query = "SELECT pe.id, pe.name, ph.phone FROM Persons pe INNER JOIN phones ph ON pe.id = ph.person_id ";
$results = mysql_query($query);
if($results && mysql_num_rows($results)) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
        if(!$return[$row['id']]) {
          $return[$row['id']] = array('name' => $row['name'], 'Phones' => array());
        } 
        array_push($return[$row['id']]['Phones'], $row['phone']);
    }
}         
return $return;
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the person first, and then query for each of the phone numbers.

```
$return = array();
$query = "SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `Persons`";
$person_results = mysql_query($query);
if($person_results && mysql_num_rows($person_results)) {
  while($person_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($person_results)) {
    $person = array();
    $person['name'] = $person_row['name'];
    $person['phone'] = array();
    $query = "SELECT `number` FROM `Phones` WHERE `person_id` = '{$person_row['id']}'";
    $phone_results = mysql_query($query);
    if($phone_results && mysql_num_rows($phone_results)) {
      while($phone_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($phone_results)) {
        array_push($person['phone'], $phone_row['number']);
      }
    }
  }
}
return $return;
```

Comment: I highly doubt that this is faster than doing one sql query and then reorder the array in php.

Comment: Umm thank you for your reply but yes that'd be around 100k+ mySQL queries, thats terribly inefficient.

Comment: You're right. I think the JOIN would work and then you can just sort through the results that way. Iterate through the results. If the name is in your buffer array, add the number. If it's not, add the name to the buffer and then add the number.